# how to calculate exp(x)

Tags: math

Could someone explain me how to calculate "exp"?

Basically I have to calculate intrinsic density for silicon at T = 200K
$$n_i=(N_cN_v)^{1/2}exp(-\frac{E_G}{2E_T})[cm^{-3}]$$

$$\sqrt{N_c N_v}=1.3173\times10^{19}$$
$$E_G=1.14736$$
$$-\frac{E_G}{2E_T}=-33.35$$

I need to calculate \$exp(-33.35)\$

How can I calculate \$exp(x)\$?

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design. Question should be closed.

Comment: yea I know, but I'm SO user and hoped I might get some help here, as this has nothing to do with programming :/

Comment: Maybe try http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Um, calculator?  Am I missing something?

Comment: yep, it's a function and if I calculate exp(x) using wolframalpha I get correct solution but what does that function stands for and how can I calculate it using calculator?

Comment: @AngryEE I agree it's off topic. For anecdotal context, I never saw this notation until I was half-way through college. People just started using it and assumed you knew what it meant.

Comment: If you really want to calculate exp(x) (not just find its value), this Wikipedia article includes a power series approximation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\$exp(x)\$ can also be written as \$e^x\$. Most scientific/graphing calculators will have this as a function. The number *e* is a constant irrational number approximately equal to 2.71828183.

Note that Google will solve this if you use "exp(x)" as well as "e^x".

Comment: On Windoze calculator it's `inv` `ln`

Comment: @FedericoRusso So clever with the "Windoze".

Comment: @FedericoRusso Windows 10 calculator have separate buttons for \$e^x\$ and \$ln\$. No need to do that anymore. However EXP on Windows calculator is used for scientific notation, just like on many pocket calculators